# Django API specifications and dot notation

Tags: django

Is there a tree for the Django dot notation where someone can quickly navigate and discover what are the options for the dot operator of a sub class?

For example I can have

`models.ForeignKey`

`models.DateTime`

`models.CharField`

`etc. etc.`

But what are all my options?
I know I have to look for inheritance (i.e., check for example in parent classes django.db.models ) but I was wondering if you are aware of a place where all this info is gathered in one place ( like this for example for java `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/` )

Comment: Read [**this**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/) and 'Variables and lookups' part in particular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here exists an effort. It is detailed and you can find class hierarchies, memberships etc...

http://fossies.org/dox/Django-1.8.2/classes.html

Answer (score 1):

That's not Django, that's python. The dot-notation is used for object paths, not for inheritance. You did this:

```
from django.db import models
```

This is a python instruction, telling the interpreter to locate the module `django.db`, lookup `models` in it and make it available in current context. It happens that this specific item is a submodule. This is possible because in python modules are actual objects (some kind of singletons).

What you probably just want to know is what's inside this module. If so, you may either look at [Django's fields documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#field-types) or list the content of the module in python shell, using `dir(models)` (will return lots of useless stuff).

By the way, those are equivalent:

```
from django.db import models
foo = models.CharField(max_length=42)
bar = models.IntegerField()

from django.db.models import CharField, IntegerField
foo = CharField(max_length=42)
bar = IntegerField()
```